# Editing custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I've to do some edits to wordPress theme home page . This is the scenario.

There are 4 posts being showed in home page under news tab now when i check this is using front-page template and in front-page template I've something like this

```
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    $loop = new WP_Query(  array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 4 , 'orderby ' => 'date' , 'order' => 'DESC' )  );
           // $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Now when i try to find out post type for news i dont find it .so if there is no custom post type for this what could be other option for this? please someone help me with it how can i figure this out .

Comment: change `news` in above code with your custom post type name.

Comment: @Roberthue if there is no tab for news section in dashboard then how do i trace from where this content is being generated ?

Comment: type the following into your url box:

domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=news

The most common reason for a post type not being shown is that it's been given the same "place" as another CPT (usually a plugin) so it's not shown, turn off all plugins to see if it comes back, if it does then find the code for the cpt and change it's "menu_position" in the register_post_type code.

Comment: invalid post type , means  does not exist